# How do I split a varchar2 in Oracle using regex(including null values)?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, split

I've been dealing with a problem that's been bothering me since yesterday. I can't split strings with a separator (like the "|" pipe) that contains empty strings. For example, my string `foo||bar|job|` I applied the query

```
select REPLACE(regexp_substr('foo||bar|job|','[^|]*(|)?',1,level),'|') output, level
from dual
connect by level <= length(regexp_replace('foo||bar|job|','[^|]+')) + 1
ORDER BY level
```

Yet it doesn't return the good result. I get :

```
1. foo
2. 
3. 
4. bar
5.
```

I also tried this solution ( [ORACLE PL-SQL How to SPLIT a string and RETURN the list using a Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374326/oracle-pl-sql-how-to-split-a-string-and-return-the-list-using-a-function) ) but I cannot adapt it to strings with "|" separator.

```
with tbl(str) as (select 'foo||bar|job|' from dual ) 
select regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(/||$)', 1, level, null, 1) element 
from tbl connect by level <= regexp_count(str, '|')+1;
```

The output is a table containing only 13 empty strings.
What I should except is this kind of list (or table) :

```
1. foo
2. 
3. bar
4. job
5.
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with tbl(str) as (select 'foo||bar|job|' from dual ) 
select level, regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, level, null, 1) e
  from tbl 
  connect by level <= regexp_count(str, '\|') + 1;
```

`|` has special meaning in regular expressions so if you want to adapt mentioned answer you need to precede pipe with backslash telling Oracle to treat it as normal character. Use backslash in `connect by` too, this is the reason you got 14 rows instead of 5.

```
     LEVEL E
---------- -------------
         1 foo
         2 
         3 bar
         4 job
         5
```

Answer (score 2):

use `connect by` with `REGEXP_COUNT` as following:

> ```
> SQL> SELECT
>   2      REGEXP_SUBSTR('foo||bar|job|', '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL) AS RESULT,
>   3      LEVEL
>   4  FROM
>   5      DUAL
>   6  CONNECT BY
>   7      LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT('foo||bar|job|', '\|') + 1;
>
> RESULT                                                    LEVEL
> ---------------------------------------------------- ----------
> foo                                                           1
> bar                                                           2
> job                                                           3
>                                                               4
>                                                               5
>
> SQL>
> ```

If you are concerned about the **order** of the `null` and actual values then you can use the following query:

> ```
> SQL> SELECT
>   2      REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE('foo||bar|job|', '||', '|#|'), '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL)
>   3              , '#', '') AS RESULT,
>   4      LEVEL
>   5  FROM
>   6      DUAL
>   7  CONNECT BY
>   8      LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT('foo||bar|job|', '\|') + 1;
>
> RESULT                                                        LEVEL
> -------------------------------------------------------- ----------
> foo                                                               1
>                                                                   2
> bar                                                               3
> job                                                               4
>                                                                   5
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi I still got a problem. I got


`1. foo
2. bar
3. job
4.
5.
`
I excepted 
`1. foo
2. 
3. bar
4. job
5.  `

Comment: You shouldn't, @Labedos, as the second query returns correct result.