# Function to accept string parameter and return substrings usable outside of the function

Tags: oracle, regexp-substr

I want to write a function that accepts an input string, uses REGEXP_SUBSTR to parse that string into up to five substrings, and returns the substrings to the procedure that called the function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PARSER_FUNCTION
(inputString IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
subStrings VARCHAR2(100);
CURSOR C1 IS
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(inputString, '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, 1)
     , REGEXP_SUBSTR(inputString, '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, 2)
     , REGEXP_SUBSTR(inputString, '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, 3)
     , REGEXP_SUBSTR(inputString, '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, 4)
     , REGEXP_SUBSTR(inputString, '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, 5)
  FROM DUAL;
BEGIN
OPEN C1;
/* Not sure what to do here... */
RETURN subStrings;
END;
END PARSER_FUNCTION;
```

In the WHERE clause of the stored procedure that calls this function, I want to be able to compare a column to each of the five substrings, something like:

```
WHERE table_column LIKE '%' || PARSER_FUNCTION[1] || '%'
  AND table_column LIKE '%' || PARSER_FUNCTION[2] || '%'
  AND table_column LIKE '%' || PARSER_FUNCTION[3] || '%'
  AND table_column LIKE '%' || PARSER_FUNCTION[4] || '%'
  AND table_column LIKE '%' || PARSER_FUNCTION[5] || '%'
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PARSER_FUNCTION(
  inputString IN VARCHAR2,
  index       IN NUMBER
)
RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
AS
  RETURN REGEXP_SUBSTR( inputString, '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, index );
END PARSER_FUNCTION;
/
```

Or, without regular expressions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION parser_function(
  list      IN VARCHAR2,
  position  IN NUMBER,
  delimiter IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
)
RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
IS
  p_start NUMBER := 1;
  p_end   NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IF list IS NULL OR position < 1 THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  IF position > 1 THEN
    p_start := INSTR( list, delimiter, 1, position - 1 ) + 1;
    IF p_start = 1 THEN
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
  END IF;
  p_end := INSTR( list, delimiter, 1, position );
  IF p_end = 0 THEN
    p_end := LENGTH( list ) + 1;
  END IF;
  RETURN SUBSTR( list, p_start, p_end - p_start );
END;
/
```

Then you can just do:

```
WHERE table_column LIKE '%' || PARSER_FUNCTION( 'list,list2,list3', 1 ) || '%'
  AND table_column LIKE '%' || PARSER_FUNCTION( 'list,list2,list3', 2 ) || '%'
  AND table_column LIKE '%' || PARSER_FUNCTION( 'list,list2,list3', 3 ) || '%'
  AND table_column LIKE '%' || PARSER_FUNCTION( 'list,list2,list3', 4 ) || '%'
  AND table_column LIKE '%' || PARSER_FUNCTION( 'list,list2,list3', 5 ) || '%'
```

*(Note: This will work for when you are using `AND` in the where clause but might not when you are using `OR` as the 4th and 5th entries in the list don't exist so you will get a clause `AND table_column LIKE '%%'` which will always be true so you could need a bit more defensive coding to check if the return from the `PARSER_FUNCTION` is not `NULL`.)*

Or you could just get rid of the function:

```
WHERE table_column LIKE '%' || REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'list,list2,list3', '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, 1 ) || '%'
  AND table_column LIKE '%' || REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'list,list2,list3', '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, 2 ) || '%'
  AND table_column LIKE '%' || REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'list,list2,list3', '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, 3 ) || '%'
  AND table_column LIKE '%' || REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'list,list2,list3', '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, 4 ) || '%'
  AND table_column LIKE '%' || REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'list,list2,list3', '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, 5 ) || '%'
```

**Update**:

You could also convert the list to a collection and join that to your query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/
```

Then you can just do:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                   FROM   TABLE( split_String( 'list1,list2,list3' ) l
                   WHERE  t.table_column NOT LIKE '%' || l.COLUMN_VALUE || '%' )
```

This means your list can contain any number of elements and it will check them all without having to repeatedly call extract the list item using regular expressions.

Comment: I needed to call the function from four different stored procedures. I have conditioned myself to think that any time I need to use a process more than once that I need to modularize the process. After taking another look at my issue, I think getting rid of the function was the right call. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your regex does not work with a NULL list element but will return the wrong value.  Try this where the 3rd element of "listC" is expected and the 2nd element is NULL: `with tbl(col1) as (
  select 'listA,,listC,listD' from dual
)
select REGEXP_SUBSTR( col1, '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, 3 )
from tbl;`

Comment: So would you rather fix the regex once, in your function or numerous times, all over your code?  Stick with your original instinct!

Comment: @Gary_W Updated to not use a regular expression and to not require hard-coding the number of list items.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this function:

```
FUNCTION  GET_LIST_ELEMENT(string_in VARCHAR2, element_in NUMBER, delimiter_in VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',') RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    BEGIN
      RETURN REGEXP_SUBSTR(string_in, '(.*?)(\'||delimiter_in||'|$)', 1, element_in, NULL, 1);
  END GET_LIST_ELEMENT;
```

As found in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25652018/2543416

Please see that thread for a discussion that may provide some info for you.

Comment: For sub-strings this regular expression is fine but don't use it to count the number of elements: `SELECT REGEXP_COUNT( '1,2,3', '(.*?)(\,|$)' ) FROM DUAL;` It will count one too many but not always: `SELECT REGEXP_COUNT( '1,2,3,', '(.*?)(\,|$)' ) FROM DUAL;`

Comment: @MT0 Great observation! For counting elements I usually use `REGEXP_COUNT('1,2', ',') + 1`  (count the delimiters and add 1).