# Split and Sequence String - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string in one of the row:

```
PID|1||123456789^^^^VV||PIZZA^KEVIN^^^^^L||98765432||
```

I have written a SQL query which will split this up

```
select regexp_substr('PPID|1||123456789^^^^VV||PIZZA^KEVIN^^^^^L||98765432||','[^|^]+', 1, level) col1 from dual
connect by regexp_substr('PID|1||123456789^^^^VV||PIZZA^KEVIN^^^^^L||98765432||', '[^|^]+', 1, level)
is not null
```

It gives output as:

```
col1

PID
1
123456789
VV
PIZZA
KEVIN
L
98765432
```

Whereas I am looking for the following conditions:

if pipe separated, then use sequence
if cap separated, then use subsequence

The output what I am looking for:

```
col1                  col_seq

PID                   PID00
1                     PID01
(NULL)                PID02
123456789             PID03-01
(NULL)                PID03-02
(NULL)                PID03-03          
VV                    PID03-04
PIZZA                 PID04-01
KEVIN                 PID04-02
(NULL)                PID04-03
(NULL)                PID04-04
(NULL)                PID04-05
(NULL)                PID04-06
L                     PID04-07
(NULL)                PID05
98765432              PID06
(NULL)                PID07
(NULL)                PID08
```

Can someone please help me with SQL for this?

Comment: Two questions: why not PID02? And should't PID04 have one more null record, just before 'VV'?

Comment: Sorry, it should be PID02. There was a typo in the question. There are 4 caps but only 3 sub-elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Here's the simple version, which gets you col1. This works a lot better if you use [the splitting regexp substr from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648653/regex-to-select-nth-value-from-a-list-allowing-for-nulls/25652018#25652018).

```
with t as (select 'PPID|1||123456789^^^^VV||PIZZA^KEVIN^^^^^L||98765432||' as str from dual)
select regexp_substr(t.str,'(.*?)(\||\^|$)', 1, level, null, 1) col1
from t
connect by level <= regexp_count(t.str, '(.*?)(\||\^|$)');
```

Adding your second column creates some significant complexity. There's probably a graceful way to do it by joining two hierarchical queries, but I can't do that well, so I just used some analytic functions.

```
with t as (select 'PPID|1||123456789^^^^VV||PIZZA^KEVIN^^^^^L||98765432||' as str from dual)
select col1,
    'PID'
      -- count pipes seen so far
    || trim(to_char(nvl(sum(case when sep = '|' then 1 else 0 end) 
                         over (order by lev rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
                     ,0)
              ,'00')) 
    -- count hats (within a partition defined by the number of pipes seen so far)
    || CASE when sep = '^' or lag(sep) over (order by lev) = '^' THEN
        '-' || trim(to_char(row_number() over (partition by regexp_count(seen, '\|') 
                                       order by lev) - 1, '00'))
        ELSE null end as col2
from (        
    select regexp_substr(t.str,'(.*?)(\||\^|$)', 1, level, null, 1) col1,
        regexp_substr(t.str,'(.*?)(\||\^|$)', 1, level, null, 2) sep,
        level as lev,
        substr(t.str,1,regexp_instr(t.str,'(.*?)(\||\^|$)', 1, level, 0)) as seen
    from t
    connect by level <= regexp_count(t.str, '(.*?)(\||\^|$)')
    ) s
;
```

Output:

```
col1      col2
PPID      PID00
1         PID01
          PID02
123456789 PID03-01
          PID03-02
          PID03-03
          PID03-04
VV        PID03-05
          PID04
PIZZA     PID05-01
KEVIN     PID05-02
          PID05-03
          PID05-04
          PID05-05
          PID05-06
L         PID05-07
          PID06
98765432  PID07
          PID08
          PID09
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

EDIT: Well, regexp_substr and hierarchical queries are both pretty slow. I rewrote it using [MT0's recursive CTE no-regex answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371989/how-to-convert-comma-separated-values-to-rows-in-oracle). It's still pretty sloppy, I'm sure it could be cleaned up.

```
WITH ex as (select 'PPID|1||123456789^^^^VV||PIZZA^KEVIN^^^^^L||98765432||' as str from dual),
  t ( str, start_pos, end_pos ) AS
  ( SELECT str, 1, LEAST(INSTR(str, '|'),INSTR(str, '^')) FROM ex
  UNION ALL
  SELECT str,
    end_pos + 1,
    CASE WHEN INSTR(str, '|', end_pos + 1) > 0 and INSTR(str, '^', end_pos + 1) > 0 THEN
        LEAST(INSTR(str, '|', end_pos + 1),INSTR(str, '^', end_pos + 1))
        ELSE GREATEST(INSTR(str, '|', end_pos + 1),INSTR(str, '^', end_pos + 1)) END
  FROM t
  WHERE end_pos > 0
  )
select col1,
    'PID' 
    -- count pipes
    || trim(to_char(nvl(sum(case when rsep = '|' then 1 else 0 end) 
                         over (order by start_pos rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
                     ,0)
              ,'00'))
    -- count hats 
    || CASE when '^' in (lsep,rsep) THEN
        '-' || trim(to_char(row_number() over (partition by (length(seen)-length(replace(seen, '|')))
                                       order by start_pos), '00'))
        ELSE null end
              as col_seq
from (              
    SELECT str, start_pos, end_pos, 
      SUBSTR( str, start_pos, DECODE( end_pos, 0, LENGTH(str) + 1, end_pos ) - start_pos ) AS col1,
      SUBSTR( str, start_pos-1, 1) as lsep, SUBSTR(str, DECODE( end_pos, 0, LENGTH(str) + 1, end_pos ), 1) as rsep,
      SUBSTR( str, 1, DECODE( end_pos, 0, LENGTH(str) + 1, end_pos )-1 ) as seen
    FROM t) s
order by start_pos;
```

Comment: is there a more efficient query? When I try to run this on my table, it takes a really long time with just 2 rows.

Comment: updated with an answer that's probably a bit faster? But the second column still adds a lot of complexity.