# Escaping characters for use with Oracle's Xmltable

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, xmltable

I'm using `Xmltable` to convert a field of comma-delimited email addresses to a table of values.

```
WITH

data AS
  (
    select  1 ID, 'foo&bar@domain.tld,bar@domain.tld' recipients from dual
  )

select  ID, trim(COLUMN_VALUE) recipient
from    data,xmltable(('"'|| REPLACE( recipients , ',', '","') || '"'))
```

produces an error:

> [72000][19112] ORA-19112: error raised during evaluation: XVM-01003:
>   [XPST0003] Syntax error at '"foo' 1
>   "foo&bar@domain.tld","bar@domain.tld" - ^

However, when I replace the `&` with its entity value (`&amp;`):

```
WITH

DATA AS
  (
    select  1 ID, 'foo&bar@domain.tld,bar@domain.tld' recipients from dual
  )

select  ID
        -- &amp; --> &
        , replace( trim(COLUMN_VALUE), '&amp;', '&') recipient
from    data
        -- & --> &amp;
        ,xmltable(('"'|| REPLACE( replace( recipients, '&','&amp;')  , ',', '","') || '"'))
```

the query works:

```
ID,RECIPIENT
1,foo&bar@domain.tld
1,bar@domain.tld
```

I'm imaging that there might be other characters that are valid in an email address, but will be problematic for `Xmltable`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Since you asked about better ways, there's a number of other options for splitting CSV to tables. My favorite is MT0's CTE on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371989/how-to-convert-comma-separated-values-to-rows-in-oracle If you go with a regexp, be aware of the null problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648653/regex-to-select-nth-value-from-a-list-allowing-for-nulls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [the built-in `dbms_xmlgen.convert()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_XMLGEN.html#GUID-E006CE92-BBCD-4479-9D30-CD74A4C7CC9A):

```
with data (id, recipients) as
(
  select 1, 'foo&bar@domain.tld,bar@domain.tld' from dual
)
select d.id, dbms_xmlgen.convert(x.column_value.getstringval(), 1) as recipient
from data d
cross join
xmltable(('"' || replace(dbms_xmlgen.convert(d.recipients, 0), ',', '","') || '"')) x

        ID RECIPIENT                     
---------- ------------------------------
         1 foo&bar@domain.tld            
         1 bar@domain.tld
```

The inner call `dbms_xmlgen.convert(d.recipients, 0)` gives you

```
foo&amp;bar@domain.tld,bar@domain.tld
```

After that has been modified to have double quotes around each comma-separated value and been split into multiple rows, you end up with `column_value` as:

```
foo&amp;bar@domain.tld
bar@domain.tld
```

so the outer `dbms_xmlgen.convert(x.column_value.getstringval(), 1)` converts any encoded entities back to their plain versions.

If you do this in a PL/SQL context then you can use `dbms_xmlgen.entity_encode` and `dbms_xmlgen.entity_decode` instead of the fixed 0 and 1, but those aren't available in plain SQL.

(There are [only five entities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/266304) to worry about anyway, but you still might as well allow for them all - whether they are valid in email addresses or not - and using a function call like this is maybe going to be less confusing to future maintainers...)

Comment: The `dbms_xmlgen.convert(d.recipients, 0)` works correctly.  The `dbms_xmlgen.convert(x.column_value.getstringval(), 1) ` generates an error `42000][904] ORA-00904: "X"."COLUMN_VALUE"."GETSTRINGVAL": invalid identifier`.

Comment: @craig - this works exactly as posted in 11.2.0.4 and later (including [in 18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fb9950bb8fa48167fcdc21cc9e0c28e7)); it doesn't work [in 11.2.0.2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3120127158401aaaa00a1d1efce30b96) but for a different reason. Unclear why it would matter but which version are you on? (I've just noticed that the `x` alias for the XMLTable expression might have required horizontal scrolling to be visible - I've split that onto a new line to stop that, just in case you'd just missed it...)